# Find the area of the surface obtained by revolving $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ about the x-axis?

Tags: calculus

So I began by choosing my formulas:

Since I know the curve is being rotated around the x-axis I choose $2\pi\int yds$

where $y=f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$

$ds=\sqrt{1+[f'(x)]^2}$

When I compute ds, I find that $ds=\sqrt{x^6-2x^4+x^2+1}$

Therefore, my integral becomes: $2\pi\int(1-x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}\sqrt{x^6-2x^4+x^2+1}dx$

Am I on the right track, because this integral itself seems very hard to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

$$f'(x) = -\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \implies 1+f'(x)^2 = \frac{1}{1-x^2}$$

Comment: oh i can't believe how many times i took the derivative wrong, i completely forgot about the exponent, how embarassing. thank you!

Comment: yes this made it a lot simpler, i got it! thank you!

Comment: Note: the curve is a half-circle with radius $1$.  After you rotate it you get a sphere of radius $1$.  The surface area of a sphere is $4\pi r^2$, which, here, is $4\pi$.